# android generate resource on the fly

Tags: java, android, resources

I would like to generate a pressend button design and load it on the fly.

The static version it is an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- selected state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_back_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_back_pressed" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_back_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!-- unselected state (default) -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_back_normal"/>

</selector>
```

which is located in the /res/drawable folder. When I want to use it just a line of the code:

```
android:background="@drawable/bt_back"
```

Now, the current project loads the design for the button from the server side, let it be the    bt_back_normal.png loaded from www.somehost.com/some/resource/bt_back_normal.png.

It would be nice if I could get an API to generate the "pressed" version ( some darker) and link it at events chain to show, when needed.

Right now there is no visual effect, when the user press the button.

How can I generate that xml equivalent on the fly? -generate a pressed version and set to show when needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`StateListDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) class. You can create these in code, add states to it (e.g. your downloaded pressed png file) and then set it to your button with `button.setBackgroundDrawable(stateList)`.

Comment: +1, very probably. Today need to work in other project can't test and aceept, but probanly this will be accepted as how the name of the class sounds

Comment: tested: it is working, but if I have 2x buttons, which have a "button_general" background, and I am generation on the fly the pressed version and put it to the StateListDrawable and set for all button, than if I press button1, it will show the explected result at buttonX, which is the last button for what I sat the same instance of StateListDrawable. StateListDrawable it isn't cloneable...

Comment: Yup, unfortunately you have to create a new StateListDrawable for each button, else as you've seen you get some weird results. I ran into this problem myself!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this on the fly. If you wanna use dynamically generated pressed drawables you should implement OnTouchListener and set needed background inside of it.

Comment: +1, I know it isn't a standard way, but I want to do it, even if in ugly, hacking way

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a workaround for that, but you could just override the OnClickListener for the button, and change the background of the button inside there. ie.

```
final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.button_pressed);
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

I didn't realize you wanted to change the states; thought you just wanted to show it was pressed. In that case, use StateListDrawable: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

Comment: "R.drawable.button_pressed" it is a static

Comment: Your code will set constant background after click. No selection depending on state (pressed/released).

Comment: "How can I generate that xml equivalent on the fly?" I have presented the static way, I want to generate his equivalent in fly, runtime, with dynamically loaded resource from server, like I have described

Comment: Then try using StateListDrawable: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html